# How to copy data from one .NET instance to another only if the properties have been changed?

Tags: c#, .net

I wish to copy data from one instance of a .NET class to another instance of the *same* class but only for the properties that have been modified/changed.

eg.

```
// Read some data from a file. Only 3 fields were read in. 
// (The rest of the properties were not touched so they have 
//   their default values).
var sourceFoo = Foo.LoadFromFile("c:\....\foo.json");

// Load up a Foo from a Db. This has .. say .. 100 properties and stuff, set.
var destinationFoo = db.GetFoo(1);

// Now copy over only those 3 changed properties.
destinationFoo.Copy(sourceFoo);
```

So far, I've created a `bool IsPropertyNameModified` for *each* property, in every class. When I do the `Copy`, I only set the value (on the `destinationFoo`) if the `IsPropertyNameModified` is `true`. That's a very simplistic summary of the code.

For collections, it's very ugly but I think I need to disallow setting a collection and only offer `AddProduct(..)` .. etc methods to add.

eg. (basically)

```
public class Foo : Baa
{
    private int _age;
    public int Age { get { return _age; } set { _age = value; IsAgeModified = true; }
    public bool IsAgeModified { get; set; }
}
```

I was hoping to use `events` to handle this waaay better. Even going so far as using `IPropertyNotified` or something. I was even thinking about making a custom class for each type we use (not many -> `int/string/bool` are basically it) which has the value and the `IsModified` setting.

I'm not sure which way is cleaner and better. I feel that my current way *smells* too much.

## UPDATE (from comments and q's)

Please don't get hung up about the fact that `destinationFoo` was loaded from a DB. It's irrelivent. The point I was trying to make was that `destinationFoo` has lots of properties *with data already being set* to them. It's *populated with data*. Now, the `sourceFoo` is the same class but has only THREE properties that were changed. As such, those three properties need to be copied. Not all the other 97 *defaults* (think `0`'s or `nulls`, etc). *That's why* I need to know which 3 properties were changed/modified and thus, copy only those.

Comment: are either `sourceFoo` or `destinationFoo` being edited through some sort of UI or are you just loading one from a file and another from a db then comparing them?  which one would need an event handler?

Comment: what benefit are you looking to achieve? e.g. performance? less network traffic?

Comment: do you want to apply a patch of what has changed to another instance with its own changes?

Comment: Definitely feels like premature optimization and the code smell is enormous.  I think you have three options: continue what you're doing which feels like a MASSIVE maintenance headache, use observables/Rx to fire events whenever a property does change, clone the object whenever any property changes.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding why someone would want to copy a db item to a file or vice versa.  The whole point to a DB in an RDBMS is to store the thing in a file with a query language on top of it.  Unless this is for some sort of migration process, like taking an XML dump of old database and importing it into new database.  In which case Entity Framework will handle that "tracking" automatically.  TLDR, knowing the goal of doing this would help us offer better solutions.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this.  I created an abstract class called `ChangeTracker` that keeps track of the changes in a list.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo() { Name = "Glenn", Age = 34, Notes = "sample code" };
        Foo bar = new Foo();
        bar.Apply(foo.GetTrackedChanges());

        // ... 
    }
}

public class Foo : ChangeTracker
{
    public Foo()
    {
    }

    private int _age;

    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set { _age = value; Track("Age", value); }
    }

    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; Track("Name", value); }
    }

    private string _notes;

    public string Notes
    {
        get { return _notes; }
        set { _notes = value; Track("Notes", value); }
    }

    private string _favoriteColor;

    public string FavoriteColor
    {
        get { return _favoriteColor; }
        set { _favoriteColor = value; Track("FavoriteColor", value); }
    }


}

// this abstract class does the work
public abstract class ChangeTracker : IChangeTrackerResetable
{
    protected List<Tuple<string, object>> _changes = new List<Tuple<string, object>>();
    public IEnumerable<Tuple<string, object>> GetTrackedChanges()
    {
        return _changes;
    }

    void IChangeTrackerResetable.Reset()
    {
        _changes.Clear();
    }

    protected void Track(string propname, object value)
    {
        _changes.Add(Tuple.Create(propname, value));
    }

    public void Apply(IEnumerable<Tuple<string, object>> changes)
    {
        var inst = this;
        var props = inst.GetType().GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach(var ch in changes)
        {
            var property = props.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == ch.Item1);
            if (property != null)
            {
                property.SetValue(inst, ch.Item2);
            }
        }

        // reset afterwards
        var o = this as IChangeTrackerResetable;
        o.Reset();
    }
}

public interface IChangeTrackerResetable
{
    void Reset();
}
```

Comment: This is a very crude, quick-n-dirty version of a pattern in MVVM, specifically I'm familiar with MVVMLight, and the ViewModelBase class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: I've never used it, but a quick nuget search led me to Change-Tracking and the description "Track changes in your poco objects and collections".

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChangeTracking/

It depends on Castle.Core and has an AsTracking extension similar to the way Entity Framework turns on/off tracking.

Comment: yes, I agree the track() call can be done in OnpropertyChanged() of Foo when it implements INPC, with [CallerMemberName] so that there won't be any mis - spelled property names for tracking.